# La comparación de valores devuelve un resultado inesperado

Tags: python-3.x

resulta que realizo un ejercicio simple y me llevo la sorpresa de que mi código esta aparentemente bien escrito, sin embargo falla, verán al probar inserto la w y lo que debería hacer el salir del bucle, sin embargo continua repitiéndose...

```
letra = "r"

while True:

    laEleccion = input("inserte una letra; ")
    if laEleccion == letra or laEleccion == "R":
        print(f"buen trabajo, la {letra}, es la correcta")
        break
    if "w" == laEleccion == "W":
        print("esa esta prohibida!!")
        break
print("END")
```

---

[image: acá un ejemplo de lo que quiero decir.]
No se si tenga algo que ver con el editor o con el computador, pero incluso en consola falla de la misma manera.

Comment: Esto: if "w" == laEleccion == "W" es falso siempre.. W no es igual a w nunca...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu segundo condicional no es correcto, la expresión es siempre evaluada como False

```
if "w" == laEleccion == "W":
```

es una comparación encadenada que es equivalente a:

```
if "w" == laEleccion and laEleccion == "W":
```

la única diferencia es que es un poco más eficiente porque el intérprete solo evalúa `laEleccion` una vez, mientras que con `and`, si la primera condición se cumple, `laEleccion` se evalúa una segunda vez.

Lo anterior por lógica es siempre `False`, `laEleccion` no puede ser simultáneamente igual a `"w"` y a `"W"`... Dicha expresión cae simpre en uno de estos tres supuestos:

```
- Se ingresa "w" ------------------- if True and False: -> False
- Se ingresa "W" ------------------- if False and True: -> False
- Se ingresa cualquier otra cosa: -- if False and False: -> False
```

Debes usar un `or` como haces en el primero, es más, para simplificar puedes usar `str.lower` o `str.upper` para "normalizar" la cadena ingresada:

```
letra = "r"

while True:
    eleccion = input("inserte una letra; ").lower()
    if eleccion == letra:
        print(f"Buen trabajo, la {letra}, es la correcta")
        break
    elif eleccion == "w":
        print("esa esta prohibida!!")
        break

print("END")
```

No uses `if` encadenados cuando son claramente excluyentes entre si (si la letra es una "r" no puede ser ya una "w", no tiene sentido evaluarlo siquiera). Si haces esto, todos son evaluados aunque uno se cumpla, lo cual es ineficiente. Usa `if-elif` en su lugar, en el momento que el `if` o un `elif` se cumpla el resto del bloque ni se evalúa.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias, un comentario completamente acertado, estuve estudiando el funcionamiento de esos condicionales y comprendí completamente tu respuesta, te lo agradezco mucho!! y tomare en cuenta cada consejo.

Comment: @KellynAlexanderGutiérrez recuerda aceptar la respuesta si te sirvio